# ob_get_contents and html string in textbox

Tags: php, html

Question is simply easy, but it seems I can't find solution so..

I'm getting html string from file using:

```
ob_start();
require_once 'view/form.php';
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

And it works, then I'm putting this string in text box using

```
echo '<br /><textarea style="width:100%" rows="10">'.$html.'</textarea>';
```

But html goes out messy with lots of white spaces and tabs, is there a way to format it in decent way to be more readable?

Comment: Just format it in whatever file is producing the html that you are reading from the buffer

Comment: And don't forget to use `htmlspecialchars` to escape your html, otherwise you will make your output invalid and might break your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/tidy.parsestring.php) (or any other HTML prettifier) to prettify HTML.

```
ob_start();
require_once 'view/form.php';
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$config = array('indent' => TRUE, 'output-xhtml' => TRUE); 
$prettyhtml = tidy_parse_string($html, $config, 'UTF8');
```

But please do take a look at the link provided, to see a cleaner, more thorough example.

This requires the tidy extension to be installed with your php install. On Ubuntu, you can install it using `apt-get install php5-tidy`. If installing extensions is not a possibility, do a quick search for 'php html prettify', and I'm sure you'll be able to find a prettifier class you can include, such as [htmLawed](http://www.bioinformatics.org/phplabware/internal_utilities/htmLawed/index.php).

If you want to display the HTML in your textbox, make sure you escape it before echoing it, so it's not actually interpreted as HTML in the browser.